# same png, same xampp, one transparent?

Tags: html, png, transparency, alpha

i can't figure out why i have 2 html documents with same png, both working from the same xampp environment, but the new one have a transparent part that is unwanted. i've tried  `opacity:1.0` without success. i'm on chrome, so no IE strange things.
I've checked the css (both made by me) and there's no relevants diffs between the styles.
I really getting creazy wit this problem!

Comment: have you checked both files in photoshop? maybe there is a difference between the 2 png's

Comment: the pngs are the same, i mean, same image from the same folder

Comment: OK, i'm really dumb! i was working with a slightly different background color... i pick the wrong HEX from the other css. i'm really srry about the stupid question!

Comment: happens to the best too.